# Python: do while loop equivalent using map

Tags: python, sorting

Is there a way to continue calling a function only if a condition is met without using loops/recursion/comprehension? I can only use map and filter.

I am bubble sorting a list and I need to reiterate until there is one whole pass without any swap. I use a counter for this.

This is what I have so far:

```
def sort(l, i, cnt):
    if i < len(l) - 1 and l[i] > l[i+1]:
        l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
        cnt += 1
  
    return l[i]
    

def main(l):
    cnt = 0
    l = list(map(lambda i: sort(l, i, cnt), range(len(l))))
```

I'm not sure how to continue calling sort only if cnt != 0. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a bubble sort with only `map` and `filter`? I guess it is some kind of educational exercise, but you are learning how to abuse `map` and `filter`, not how to use them sensibly.

Comment: Is it bubble sort specifically that you have to implement, or just any sort?

Comment: Any sort will do. I chose bubble sort because it seemed the simplest at the time.

Comment: Is there any constraint on the list elements, e.g. are they integers within a certain range?

Comment: They are integers between 1 and 50, although some might be skipped.

Comment: Then you should use counting sort, not bubble sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is un uncommon requirement, but it is possible, provided you are allowed to use other functions to actually execute the iterators. Because both `map` and `filter` both only return iterators, so you will have to use `sum`, `list`, or `tuple` for example to actually cause the iterators to return their values.

Here I would use a function that compares 2 consecutive elements in a list, returns 0 in they are in increasing order and swap them and returns 1 if they are not. Using `sum` on a `map` on this function will return the number of swaps on a pass:

```
def sort2(l, i):
    if (l[i] > l[i+1]):
        l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
        return 1
    return 0
```

You can the execute a *pass* with:

```
sum(map(lambda i: sort2(l, i), range(len(l) -1)))
```

And you execute a full bubble sort by using a second map for all the passes:

```
sum(map(lambda j: sum(map(lambda i: sort2(l, i), range(len(l) -j))), range(1, len(l))))
```

In order to stop as soon as one pass resulted in 0 swap, I would filter with a function raising a `StopIteration`, when it gets 0, because if we use sum, a pass returns 0 as soon as the list is sorted, and the StopIteration will gently stops the iterators:

```
def stop(x):
    # print(x)   # uncomment to control the actual calls
    if x == 0:
        raise StopIteration
    return True
```

Let us combine everything:

```
tuple(filter(stop, map(lambda j: sum(map(lambda i: sort2(l, i), range(len(l) -j))
               ), range(1, len(l)))))
```

Demo:

With `l = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`, this gives (with the `print` uncommented in `stop`):

```
2
1
0
(2, 1)
```

So we have correctly got:

- first pass caused 2 swaps ((5,2) and (5,4))
- second pass caused 1 swap ((3,2))
- third pass caused 0 swap and the `stop` filter actually stopped the iterators.

That being said, it is a nice exercise, but I would never do that in real world programs...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check `itertools.takewhile`; it seems like it is the one you are looking for. See [the documentation for `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for details.

```py
takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1])
# --> 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, your goal is to sort a list of numbers between 1 and 50 using `map` and `filter` without loops, comprehensions or recursion. Therefore your actual question (about a do/while equivalent for implementing bubble sort) is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) because the correct solution is not to use bubble sort at all. When asking questions in future, please say what your actual problem is - don't just ask how to fix your attempted solution.

The [counting sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is suitable here; something akin to counting sort can be implemented using `map` and `filter` without side-effects:

```py
def counting_sort(numbers):
    min_x, max_x = min(numbers), max(numbers)
    r_x = range(min_x, max_x + 1)
    r_i = range(len(numbers))
    count_ge = list(map(sum, map(lambda x: map(x.__ge__, numbers), r_x)))
    return list(map(lambda i: min_x + sum(map(i.__ge__, count_ge)), r_i))
```

Note that this is a very inefficient variant of counting sort; it runs in O(nk) time instead of O(n + k) time. But it meets the requirements.